# Is it possible to prove the demiclosedness principle for non uniformly convex Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

The demiclosedness principle asserts that if $K$ is a closed convex subset of a **uniformly convex** Banach space $X$ and if $T:K\rightarrow X$ is nonexpansive, then $Id-T$ is demiclosed.

The proof can be found in "Nonexpansive nonlinear operators in a Banach space" by Browder (1965).

---

Do you know if it is possible to prove the same result without the requirement that the space is uniformly convex? Thank you in advice for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is a nearly uniformly convex (NUC) Banach space with Opial’s condition, $C$ is a nonempty weakly compact convex subset of $X$, and $T: C\rightarrow C$ is a mapping of asymptotically nonexpansive type and $T^N$ is continuous for some $N \geq 1$. Then $I - T$ is demi-closed at zero.

So the conclusion is that the condition UC can be relaxed to NUC.